# How to add recipients using Challonge API?

Tags: php, wordpress, api, post

Amateur coder here.

I am trying to create a way for my registration form to send registrants to Challonge tournaments as participants to auto fill the brackets once they register. I am using Ninja Forms in Wordpress with their webhook add on. When particpants are filling out the form, they select the tournaments from a checkbox list. Each label has a value that is the tournament slug.

I think I have created the correct code and using the correct API key and URL/Tournament IDs and am getting a 200 when submitting, but nothing changes within each Challonge tournament. Not receiving any errors in my php log.

I have created two files:

**functions.php within my child theme:
**

```
/**
 * Process Ninja Forms submission and create participant in Challonge tournament
 *
 * @param array $form_data
 * @return bool
 */
function process_ninja_forms_submission($form_data) {
  // Get form data
  $email = $form_data['email'];
  $gamertag = $form_data['gamertag'];
  $legal_first_name = $form_data['legal_first_name'];
  $legal_last_name = $form_data['legal_last_name'];
  $select_tournaments = $form_data['select_tournaments'];

  // Check if gamertag is empty, and replace it with legal name if necessary
  if (empty($gamertag)) {
    $gamertag = $legal_first_name . ' ' . $legal_last_name;
  }

  // Challonge API credentials
  $api_key = 'api key';
  $tournament_slug = $select_tournaments;

  // Create participant in Challonge
  $url = 'https://api.challonge.com/v1/retroworldseries/tournaments/' . $tournament_slug . '/participants.json';
  $data = array(
    'api_key' => $api_key,
    'participant[name]' => $gamertag,
    'participant[email]' => $email,
    'participant[misc]' => $legal_first_name . ' ' . $legal_last_name
  );

  $options = array(
    'http' => array(
      'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
      'method'  => 'POST',
      'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
  );

  $context  = stream_context_create($options);
  $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

  if ($result === false) {
    // Handle error
    $error_message = error_get_last();
    error_log('Challonge API Error: ' . $error_message['message']);
    return false;
  } else {
    // Participant created successfully
    error_log('Challonge API Success: Participant created successfully');
    return true;
  }
}

/**
 * Add custom field to Ninja Forms form
 *
 * @param array $fields
 * @return array
 */
function add_gamertag_field_to_ninja_forms($fields) {
  $fields['gamertag'] = array(
    'id' => 'gamertag',
    'type' => 'textbox',
    'label' => 'Gamertag',
    'width' => 'full',
    'group' => 'primary',
    'order' => 60,
    'value' => ''
  );
  return $fields;
}
add_filter('ninja_forms_field', 'add_gamertag_field_to_ninja_forms');

/**
 * Add custom processing to Ninja Forms submission
 *
 * @param array $form_data
 */
function custom_ninja_forms_processing($form_data) {
  process_ninja_forms_submission($form_data);
}
add_action('ninja_forms_post_process', 'custom_ninja_forms_processing');
```

**For the second file (process_ninja_forms.php):
**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', '/wp-content/themes/twentytwentytwo-child/php_errorlog');

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../plugins/ninja-forms/vendor/autoload.php');

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

function process_ninja_forms($form_data) {
    $email = $form_data['email'];
    $gamertag = $form_data['gamertag'];
    $first_name = $form_data['legal_first_name'];
    $last_name = $form_data['legal_last_name'];
    $tournament = $form_data['select_tournaments'];
    $tournament_slug = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $tournament));
    $api_key = 'api key';
    
    // Check if gamertag field is empty and use first and last name instead
    $participant_name = $gamertag ? $gamertag : "{$first_name} {$last_name}";
    
    // Create participant data
    $participant_data = [
        'participant' => [
            'name' => $participant_name,
            'email' => $email,
            'misc' => "{$first_name} {$last_name}"
        ]
    ];

 // Create participant in Challonge
$url = "https://api.challonge.com/v1/retroworldseries/tournaments/{$tournament_slug}/participants.json";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Return response body as string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($participant_data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($api_key . ":")
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);
$response = curl_exec($ch); // Get response body as string
echo "Response Body: " . $result . "\n";
rewind($verbose);
$log = stream_get_contents($verbose); // Get verbose log
fclose($verbose);

error_log('Challonge API URL: ' . $url);
error_log('Challonge API Data: ' . http_build_query($participant_data));
error_log('Challonge API Response: ' . $response); // Log response body
error_log('Challonge API Verbose: ' . $log); // Log verbose log

}
?>
```

For the webhook action in Ninja Forms, I added the remote URL as the process_ninja_forms.php location and the Remote Method as POST. I tested the API using ReqBin, and got a 500 response, so maybe its not my code? Challonge support is slim to none. They say they dont have the manpower to handle tech support for their API.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Please read above. Thanks